# fancybox difficulties with opening an html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fancybox

Please click on the Jade on this page: http://sneakyrascal.com/starpons/gallery.html 
I added a fancybox to its link and the pop-up html includes a gallery which is based on jQuery and css. I believe maybe it's because there's a jQuery in the html page it won't show correctly.

You can see in this page fancybox shows an image correctly so it should work with opening an html too. http://sneakyrascal.com/starpons/about.html

It works with Chrome but not correctly in Firefox and nothing in IE.

I will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the way that I've opened a fancybox window with an html ajax page in the past:

1. Define the link with the appropriate href:

   ```
     <a class="fbtag" href="/some_page.html">link</a>
   ```
2. Using jquery, assign the fbtag class (or whatever class) to open the fancybox & link:

   ```
   $('a.fbtag').fancybox();
   ```

Fancybox will take the url that you defined in the link and use it to populate the window.  You can also define any options you want in the fancybox call as well.

Comment: Thanks a million. You just saved me :)

Comment: Unfortunately this method disabled the width and height setting I will appreciate if you help me with it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7365850/width-and-height-problem-with-fancybox

Comment: Posted a reply on your other question.  I hope it helps.