# Width and height issue with fancybox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fancybox

When I've added this code no setting on width and height works

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  $('a.iframe').fancybox(); 
});
```

What are the options to get around it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Take a look at the documentation here:   http://fancybox.net/api

You're using inline content, so make sure that you're setting the autoDimensions option to false along with the width and height settings.

*UPDATE:* I tested the following solution successfully:

```
    $('a.fbtag').fancybox({
        autoDimensions: false,
        height: 300,
        width: 400
    });
```

This assumes that the class name of the link you're opening is 'fbtag'.

Comment: Thanks but I already tried that and didn't work. The setting wont' affect anything!

Comment: What's it doing?  Is it sizing itself to the html page you're feeding it?  If so, you could size that w/ CSS instead to be the appropriate size.

Comment: Yes... I tried that too... I changed #fancybox-wrap #fancybox-content #fancybox-outer but they won't fit naturally they make the box move to the left when its width is changed while showing the pop-up.

Comment: Hi - I updated my answer with the solution.  I tested it myself and it works.

Comment: Hi SBerg413 sorry for my delay, yes it works :) thanks a lot I'm using it in a new project.

Comment: If you are using [Fancybox 2](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox) then `autoDimensions` has changed to `autoSize` Where: `If true, then sets both autoHeight and autoWidth to true
Boolean; Default value: true`

Answer (score 2):

Fancy Box width and Height always varies with the media type.

If we provide 5 * 5 pixel image - Fancy Box will show up with dimensions of Image Dimensions.

To counter the effect of media dimensions and define the default width & height for Fancy Box

Try this:

```
$.fancybox.open(collection.toJSON(), {
   afterShow :function(){},
   maxHeight    : 600,
   minWidth : 500           
});
```

FancyBox width will be minimum - 500 pixels.

FancyBox Height will be proportional to the FancyBox data with maximum Height of 600 pixels.

Answer (score 1):

For example

```
$.fancybox({
    'content':"This will be the content of the fancybox",
    'width':'500',
    'autoDimensions':false,
    'type':'iframe',
    'autoSize':false
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".fancy-ajax").fancybox({
        type:           'ajax',
        autoDimensions: false,
        'autoSize':     false,
        'height':       'auto'
    });
});
```

The above codes worked for me. However, I was designing in Twitter Bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this two way

**With iframe**

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".fancybox").fancybox({
            width:600,
            height:400,
            type: 'iframe',
            href  : 'url_here'
       });
     })
```

**Without iframe**

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
        width:600,
        height:400,
        autoDimensions: false,
   });
 })
```